# Работа с указателями в golang и блокировки?

Tags: golang

Добрый день.
У меня есть ссылочная переменная var MaxData *int , которую увеличивают с каждым разом.

```
func new_data(){
    *MaxData = *MaxData +1
    internal_max_data=*MaxData // вообщем как-то хочу внутренней переменной присвоить значение MaxData и потом работать в функции с internal_max_data 
}
```

На самом деле с *MaxData могут работать в горутинах много функций new_data() 
и вот какой вопрос возникает. Теоретически можно предположить, что одна горутина увеличила MaxData,а потом вторая тоже квеличила, а потом первая присвоила internal_max_data MaxData, которая увеличена уже на 2 ...и вторая горутина в это время тоже взяла это же значение.
Ну судя из этого- программа "ляпнет".  Вообщем как-то надо что-ли заблокировать MaxData на этот промежуток времени. И вообще -как с указателями работать? а то у меня эроры везде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае, вам правильно ответили, задача решается с помощью тех же мьютексов. Но конкретно в вашем случае лучше использовать атомарные операции из модуля [atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/):

```
import "sync/atomic"

...

var MaxData *uint64 = new(uint64)

...

func new_data() {
    internal_max_data := atomic.AddUint64(MaxData, 1)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужны [средства синхронизации параллельного доступа](http://golang.org/pkg/sync).

```
import "sync"

// там же где MaxData
var maxDataLock = &sync.Mutex{}

func new_data() {
    // между Lock и Unlock одновременно может быть только 1 поток, что нам и требуется
    maxDataLock.Lock();
    *MaxData = *MaxData +1
    internal_max_data=*MaxData
    maxDataLock.Unlock();
}
```

С указателями вообще просто: 1) разобраться с ними и 2) работать.

P.S. в коде могут быть ляпы, т.к. на Go вообще не пишу. Но думаю направление моих мыслей правильное.

Comment: документация рекомендует для освобождения мютекса использовать defer.